# How to view the request being sent in c#

Tags: c#, xml, tcp, response

I am working on the following code.

```
            Int32 port = 7101;
            IPAddress localAddr1 = IPAddress.Parse("117.239.85.13");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            String message_text = "<estel><header><requesttype>CREDIT</requesttype></header><request><agentcode>910000006789</agentcode><vendorcode>HELLOTV</vendorcode><pin>***************</pin><destination>919555518484</destination><agenttransid>*****</agenttransid><amount>10</amount><productcode>SKUA</productcode><clienttype>portal</clienttype><comments>abcd</comments></request></estel>";
            doc.LoadXml(message_text);
            doc.Save(ms);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Byte[] data = ms.ToArray();

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(localAddr1, port);
            MessageBox.Show(client.Connected.ToString()); // Connection was established here. Returns TRUE value

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.AutoFlush = false;
            writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message_text).Length);

            writer.Flush();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            MessageBox.Show(stream.DataAvailable.ToString()); // Returns TRUE value


            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            string responseData;
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(client.ReceiveBufferSize));
            responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);  // We are getting response here
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            textBox1.Text = responseData.ToString();
```

Here I am sending a XML data to the web service provider using IP and Port no. After sending the request I am getting the following response 15 times

```
<estel><header><responsetype>INVALID REQUEST</responsetype></header></estel>
```

It seems some extra content is being appended. How can I view the request being sent, so that I can correct it?

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to be sending?

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.AutoFlush = false;
writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message_text).Length);
```

It looks like you are writing the length of the xml document into the stream before the content.

I expect the output you are putting in your stream to be this:
`357<estel><header><requesttype>CREDIT</requesttype></header><request><agentcode>910000006789</agentcode><vendorcode>HELLOTV</vendorcode><pin>***************</pin><destination>919555518484</destination><agenttransid>*****</agenttransid><amount>10</amount><productcode>SKUA</productcode><clienttype>portal</clienttype><comments>abcd</comments></request></estel>`

Note the number at the start. This is the length of the document.

You are doing a lot of redundant messing around with that `MemoryStream`. It is not required. For some cleaner code, remove the `ms` and `data` and try this instead:

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.AutoFlush = false;
writer.Write(doc.Value.Length); //is this line intended? Take it out, see what happens!
writer.Write(doc.Value);
writer.Flush();
```

Why does this work? `XmlNode.Value` gives you the string content of the node. In your case, this is the entire document content. Your `StreamWriter` is set up with the encoding you want to use, `UTF-8`. If you pass a string to it, it will do the `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` call for you!

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a similar program that sends request to ncell. I encounter the same problem but I found the solution. The problem lies with the xml string format. A new line is required at the end of the xml request as tested in telnet.

```
    String message_text = "<estel><header><requesttype>CREDIT</requesttype></header><request><agentcode>910000006789</agentcode>    <vendorcode>HELLOTV</vendorcode><pin>***************</pin>    <destination>919555518484</destination><agenttransid>*****</agenttransid>    <amount>10</amount><productcode>SKUA</productcode>    <clienttype>portal</clienttype><comments>abcd</comments></request></estel>"
+ Environment.NewLine;
    Byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message_text);
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```